# git pull error when working with remote repository

Tags: git, github, repository

I set up this project completely new.
I created a `remote repository` and did this on my local machine.

```
$ git init
$ git remote add origin git@...
$ git add . 
$ git commit
$ git push -u origin master
$ git branch -u origin/master
```

Then I wrote something into the readme in the `remote repository`. When I type on my local machine `git checkout master` I get this:

> Already on 'master'
>   Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast forwarded.
>   (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

However, when I try to do `$ git pull` as suggested I get this:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
>   README.md
>   Please move or remove them before you can merge.

How do I get the changes from `origin` to my `master` then?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Git says, you have to remove your untracked working tree files (in your case there is only one called 'README.md'). If you have changes you want to keep, commit them, and then do a pull.

Question: why didn't you do a `git clone ...`?

**EDIT**

When you do a `git pull`, git does a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`. The merge could be as simple as a fast-forward, if you did not divert from the remote. But if you did, git needs to merge the changes together. To make sure you do not loose any work, git complains if there are changes to a file that will be touched by a merge in your working directory.

To keep your changes you can either

1. add the file to your index (`git add README.md`), create a stash (`git stash`), do a merge (`git merge origin/master`) and pop you stash (`git stash pop`) or
2. create a commit given your changes (`git add README.md` followed by `git commit`) and then merge in the changes from the remote (`git merge origin/master`)

Comment: that seems unreasnoable. What if there are many changes in the code? Would I have to remove manually all the files that changed and then replace them by the files upstream?! I want to include the changes made upstream into the code. I tried `git fetch` and then `git merge origin` but that gave me `origin - not something we can merge` I did not do a clone because the folder where I created the repository in is not empty.

Comment: When you do a `git pull`, git does a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`. The merge could be as simple as a fast-forward, if you did not divert from the origin, but if you did, git needs to merge the changes together. To make sure you do not loose any work, git complains if there are changes to a file that will be touched by a merge in your working directory. To keep your changes you can either 1) add the file to your index, create a stash, do a merge and pop you stash or 2) create a commit given your changes and then merge in the changes from the remote. I will update my answer.

Comment: When I try `git merge origin/master` I get still the same: `error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        README.md
Please move or remove them before you can merge.`

Comment: Yes, you have to make sure the README.md file is either committed, or (temporarily) removed. Please, follow one of the proposed solutions in the answer.

Comment: Yes but I want to understand. What do you mean by `committed`? Why do I need to `commit` something, that is not there?! And what happens if some code gets changed. Would I have to do `git add 100 files of code manually` as well?!

Comment: What I understand is that there is a file in your working directory called 'README.md', which is a file not currently tracked by git, meaning it is not referenced by your HEAD. That file is the problem, and should be removed or committed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123796/discussion-between-yaba-and-stophface).